# how can i store a string in an array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, cs50

I tried using the strlen to count the characters and named the variable n and created an array with a name [n+1] but the variable n is not a global variable so I'm having some problems as the computer does not understand what n is. To calculate n I created another function

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_characters(string text);
int n;
int main(void)
charcters [n+1]
{
 string t = get_string("text: ");
 printf("letter(s)");

}

int count_characters(string text)
{
 n = strlen(text);
 return n;
}
```

Comment: Does the code, that you posted, compile? Looks to me like it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of values in `n` must be after the assignment to `n`.

What you want may be:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int count_characters(string text);
int n;
int main(void)
{
 string t = get_string("text: ");
 printf("letter(s)");
 /* call the function to have it assign to n */
 count_characters(t);
 /* now the length is assigned to n, so use it */
 /* also don't forget the type name for elements */
 char charcters [n+1];
 /* store a string */
 strcpy(charcters, t);

}

int count_characters(string text)
{
 n = strlen(text);
 return n;
}
```